# Windows Phone 8, need to cancel Async task on back key press

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new to WP8 Aync tasks and have a query- 
In WP8, on backbutton press, since it basically pops the last screen from the stack, then why are the Async tasks not cancelled when back key is pressed?

Also, if I am using the HttpWebRequest response, is using Abort() the only way of cancelling the async tasks?

Comment: What tasks are we talking about here, your own or from some library function?

Comment: The httpWebrequests are the async task I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because Back is a UI concept but things like networking are typically decoupled from the UI. As an example, imagine the user hit "Save" in an app and that started a web request to send their data to the cloud. Then they hit the Back button to go back to the previous page; it would be unexpected for the web request to be aborted and the data to potentially not be saved.

If you have a need to stop tasks when your UI changes (eg, because of resource consumption concerns) then you can try to do that, but I have a vague recollection that Abort is a no-op for Windows Phone 8 (but I could be wrong).